# Printing out the type of something in IO operations in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a block of code

```
main = do
   args <- getArgs --args is a list.
   ...
   let finalMappedContents = addUpSameWord mappedContents
```

For the final IO statement, I want to print out the type of finalMappedContents. How can I do this? I know of the typeOf function, but I'm not completely sure how to use that here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `showsTypeRep` in order to get the `String` representation of the type:

```hs
λ> let foo = "Foo"
λ> import Data.Typeable
λ> putStrLn $ showsTypeRep (typeOf foo) ""
[Char]
```

In your case it would be:

```hs
putStrLn $ showsTypeRep (typeOf finalMappedContents) ""
```

**Edit**

Thanks to @dfeuer for pointing out that you can also just use the `Show` instance:

```hs
print $ typeOf finalMappedContents
```

Comment: Why not just `print (typeOf finalMappedContents)`? `Data.Typeable.TypeRep` and `Type.Reflection.TypeRep t` both have `Show` instances, I believe.

Comment: @dfeuer good point. Added to the answer.